# Spring Boot 3.0.2 adds "continue" query parameter to request URL after login

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I just upgraded my project from Spring boot 2.7.7 to 3.0.2 and I'm seeing some weird behavior.
When I login to my application Spring adds "continue" query parameter to URL. It wasn't like this in 2.7.7. Is there something which I'm missing?

I use formLogin and have implemenatation of AuthenticationSuccessHandler, though it doesn't add any parameters.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is covered in Spring Security's [migration guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/session-management.html#requestcache-query-optimization).

Basically, the query parameter was added to make so that Spring Security knows whether to query the session on that request or not. It is a performance optimization.

You can change the value by configuring the `RequestCache` like so:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain springSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    HttpSessionRequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
    requestCache.setMatchingRequestParameterName("mycustomparameter");
    http
        // ...
        .requestCache((cache) -> cache
            .requestCache(requestCache)
        );
    return http.build();
}
```

Or, if you don't want this performance optimization, you can turn it off in the same way:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain springSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    HttpSessionRequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
    requestCache.setMatchingRequestParameterName(null);
    http
        // ...
        .requestCache((cache) -> cache
            .requestCache(requestCache)
        );
    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: Can someone explain why "getting the session on every request" is a problem? In HttpSessionRequestCache#getMatchingRequest (spring-security-web 61.5) at first glance I can't find a  problematic spot (and plan to remove the "continue"-Parameter).

Comment: It's been a common complaint about Spring Security over the years, that it's very eager to pull up the session, even on requests where it doesn't end up using it. Using the session does two unwanted things: 1. Potentially creates a session where none was wanted, 2. Loads up a session, exercising resources unnecessarily to do so. In short, it's a performance optimization.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of *SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler*.

First it gets the request Cache like this:

```
SavedRequest savedRequest = this.requestCache.getRequest(request, response);
```

and uses it like this

```
String targetUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();

getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
```

If you want to turn off the referer you can do that with

```
setUseReferer(false);
```

in your Constructor.