# Vaadin 'continue' url parameter

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin24

I noticed that sometimes Vaadin adds 'continue' parameter to the url, for example:

Redirecting to https://example.com/profile?continue&continue&continue&continue

What does this mean? And is it possible to disable such behavior?

Comment: It comes from the HttpSessionRequestCache used within the default security implementation. Overwrite it, if you know what you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. As described above it comes form Springs HttpSessionRequestCache. It is a performance optimization feature and could be removed

[Spring Boot 3.0.2 adds "continue" query parameter to request URL after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75222930/spring-boot-3-0-2-adds-continue-query-parameter-to-request-url-after-login)

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain springSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    HttpSessionRequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
    requestCache.setMatchingRequestParameterName(null);
    http
        // ...
        .requestCache((cache) -> cache
            .requestCache(requestCache)
        );
    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, I'd like to add that I may be wrong, but looks like the issue is gone with SB 3.1.2 Now I have only one 'continue' always in the url