PermitAll() is not working for homepage(Spring boot security)
I have a Spring Boot application where I am using multiple projects with Eureka Server.                  i am trying to access the homepage though the consumer application with the help of Eureka Server but somehow its asking for authentication.
when i provide the login details it redirects me to http://localhost:8082/WEB-INF/pages/homepage.jsp?continue But when i change the URL after the authorization to http://localhost:8082/homepage it displays the Home page(i tried to change the URL before authentication but it doesn't work it simply redirects me to default login page of Spring Security)
Sorry if i have any grammatical error.
@Controller
public class ConsumerController {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate template;
    


    @GetMapping("/homepage")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("Home page accessed");
        return "homepage";
    }
     @GetMapping("/")
        public String defaultHome() {
            return "redirect:/homepage"; // Redirect root URL to homepage
        }
       // Other controller methods...
}

application.properties
#View Resolver
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/pages/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

#Sever Port
server.port=8082

eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${random.value}
eureka.instance.homePageUrl=http://192.168.1.42:8082/homepage
eureka.instance.statusPageUrl=http://192.168.1.42:8082/homepage
eureka.instance.healthCheckUrl=http://localhost:8761/actuator/health

#Other property configurations....

SecurityConfig.class
package com.yo.Trust.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    UserDetailsService getUserDetailsService() {

        return new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(getUserDetailsService());
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }

     @Bean
        SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                    .requestMatchers("/", "/homepage","/actuator/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/eureka/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/addCustomer").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "CUSTOMER")
                    .requestMatchers("/allCust").hasRole("MANAGER")
                    .requestMatchers("/showFindCustomerForm","/getCustById").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "CUSTOMER")
                    .requestMatchers("/showCheckBalanceForm", "/checkCurentBalance").hasRole("CUSTOMER")
                    .requestMatchers("/addEmployee", "/addEmployeeForm").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "EMPLOYEE")
                    .requestMatchers("/getallBankemp").hasRole("MANAGER")
                    .requestMatchers("/showFindEmpForm", "/findBankEmpById").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "EMPLOYEE")
                    .requestMatchers("/updateEmployee", "/updateEmployeeForm").hasRole("MANAGER")
                    .requestMatchers("/updateDeptnoForm", "/updateDeptno").hasRole("MANAGER")
                    .requestMatchers("/loanForm", "/loan").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(form -> form
                    .permitAll() 
                )
                .logout(logout -> logout
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/consumer/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                    .permitAll()
                );

            http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
            return http.build();
        }

 }


Try this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75222930/spring-boot-3-0-2-adds-continue-query-parameter-to-request-url-after-login

Hi, Thank you for replying! i have tried the 2nd approach which disables performance as mentioned in the link you provided, now its not redirecting to "http://localhost:8082/WEB-INF/pages/homepage.jsp?continue" but instead its simply directing to "http://localhost:8082/WEB-INF/pages/homepage.jsp" , that homepage.jsp exist in the location which i have mentioned in the example code & my code was working fine until i implemented the Spring Security.
